# How to show Datagridviews selected row at first row position

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

My Datagridview has records from sql server 2000, in which one datagridview row is associated with the current data displayed on form. I am highlighting the associated datagridview row. But I want to show that row on the first position. So how can I perform this? Is this possible or not? If yes, any help would be highly appreciable.

Thanks and regards,
Rizwan Gazi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that

> I am highlighting the associated datagridview row.

means `dataGridView1.CurrentRow = your highlighted row`, all you have to do is the following:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
```

As long as the number of existing `DataGridViewRows` are enough to enable scrolling, this will work.  Note that a small number of rows won't *appear* to work, but that's trivial.

Comment: So dear @OhBeWise, won't the above solution work, if I don't have much rows in my datagriview?

Comment: Great dear, it worked. I understood that there must be much enough rows to scroll down. Otherwise it won't work. You correctly pointed it out dear  @OhBeWise. Once again many thanks for considering the question and replying the best solution.